# Converting Audio of Paced breathing to plot

Tags: sound

This is for a research project on meditation.  A music-type person composed for me an audio for paced breathing, which consists of some undulating tones.  I would like to convert it to a smooth function for data analysis, where I will compare the function to some laboratory measurements, like heart rate. Here is a link to the audio [file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/l8aavar189d4b2x/BPM%208.wav?dl=0): Here is my code.

```
audio = Audio[File["BPM 8.wav"]];
selectData = MovingAverage[selectData, 20020]; 
ListLinePlot[selectData, PlotRange -> All, AspectRatio -> 1/10]
```

Here is the [result](https://www.dropbox.com/s/27u7jos107pst1p/Untitled.pdf?dl=0)

If I increase the moving average window, it loses its features. If I decrease the window, the result obviously gets noisier.   I can't seem to a get a smooth function that has the features of this very regular tone.

Comment: hmm...what features do you want to extract? volume? pitch? If you take an average of a sound wave, you'll have a lot of cancellation in each of the pitch components (imagine the average of a sine wave over a long time). If you want to represent the volume, maybe take the root mean square over a certain window, or the maximum value over a certain window? But first you've got to decide on the abstract features you want before implementing them! :)

Comment: I don't really care what feature I extract.   I just want to correlate the audio with some laboratory measurements (HRV, if you've heard of that) in meditators.  But anyway, after I posted the above question, I realized that I really need to take the absolute value of the data file.  Your idea of the root mean squared is probably even better.  So thanks for that!

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest looking at the `Audio*` functionality for maximum efficiency. I'd do something like:

```
a = Audio["/Users/carlogico/Downloads/BPM 8.wav"];

AudioPlot[a]
Spectrogram[a]

AudioLocalMeasurements[a, "RMSAmplitude", 
  PartitionGranularity -> {Quantity[0.2, "Seconds"], 
    Quantity[0.1, "Seconds"]}] // ListLinePlot
```

Some pages to look at:

- https://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/AudioRepresentation.html
- https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AudioLocalMeasurements.html
- https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AudioBlockMap.html

Comment: This looks like the answer I'm looking for.  I will try to implement your suggestion in coming days, and if it works I'll remember to attribute the answer to  you. thanks.